# Jest stop test suite after first fail

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) for testing.

What I want, is to stop executing the current test suite when a test in that test suite fails.

The [`--bail` option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--bail) is not what I need, since it will stop other test suites after one test suite fails.

Comment: This is a great question, and I'm surprised Jest appears to have no guidance for this situation. I've filed a [ticket on their GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6695).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I think this is more about the hooks throwing an error. As the OP asks in case a tests fail what can we do?

Answer (score 7):

I have sequential and complicated test scenarios, where there was no point to continue test suit if one of tests of this suite failed. But I have not managed to mark them as skipped, so they are shown as passed.

example of my test suite:

```
describe('Test scenario 1', () => {

test('that item can be created', async () => {
    expect(true).toBe(false)
})

test('that item can be deleted', async () => {
    ...
})
...
```

which I changed to the following:

```
let hasTestFailed = false
const sequentialTest = (name, action) => {
    test(name, async () => {        
      if(hasTestFailed){
        console.warn(`[skipped]: ${name}`)} 
      else {
          try {         
            await action()} 
          catch (error) {           
            hasTestFailed = true
            throw error}            
      }
    })
  }
describe('Test scenario 1', () => {
    
sequentialTest('that item can be created', async () => {
        expect(true).toBe(false)
})
    
sequentialTest('that item can be deleted', async () => {
        ...
})
```

If the first test will fail, the next tests won't run, but they will get status Passed.

**The report will look like:**

- Test scenario 1 > that item can be created - **Failed**
- Test scenario 1 > that item can be deleted - **Passed**

That is not ideal, but acceptable in my case since I want to see only failed tests in my reports.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [this comment on github](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8387#issuecomment-760149304) I was able to resolve this with a custom `testEnvironment`. For this to work `jest-circus` need to be installed via `npm`/`yarn`.
It's worth noting that [jest will set jest-circus to the default runner with jest v27](https://jestjs.io/blog/2020/05/05/jest-26).

First of all jest configuration needs to be adapted:

**`jest.config.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  rootDir: ".",
  testRunner: "jest-circus/runner",
  testEnvironment: "<rootDir>/NodeEnvironmentFailFast.js",
}
```

Then you need to implement a custom environment, which is already referenced by the config above:

**`NodeEnvironmentFailFast.js`**

```js
const NodeEnvironment = require("jest-environment-node")

class NodeEnvironmentFailFast extends NodeEnvironment {
  failedDescribeMap = {}
  registeredEventHandler = []

  async setup() {
    await super.setup()
    this.global.testEnvironment = this
  }

  registerTestEventHandler(registeredEventHandler) {
    this.registeredEventHandler.push(registeredEventHandler)
  }

  async executeTestEventHandlers(event, state) {
    for (let handler of this.registeredEventHandler) {
      await handler(event, state)
    }
  }

  async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
    await this.executeTestEventHandlers(event, state)

    switch (event.name) {
      case "hook_failure": {
        const describeBlockName = event.hook.parent.name

        this.failedDescribeMap[describeBlockName] = true
        // hook errors are not displayed if tests are skipped, so display them manually
        console.error(`ERROR: ${describeBlockName} > ${event.hook.type}\n\n`, event.error, "\n")
        break
      }
      case "test_fn_failure": {
        this.failedDescribeMap[event.test.parent.name] = true
        break
      }
      case "test_start": {
        if (this.failedDescribeMap[event.test.parent.name]) {
          event.test.mode = "skip"
        }
        break
      }
    }

    if (super.handleTestEvent) {
      super.handleTestEvent(event, state)
    }
  }
}

module.exports = NodeEnvironmentFailFast
```

---

**NOTE**

I added `registerTestEventHandler` functionality which is not necessary for the fail fast feature, but I thought it's quite useful, especially if you used `jasmine.getEnv()` before and it works with `async`/`await`!
You can register custom handler **inside** of your tests (e.g. `beforeAll` hook) like so:

```js
// testEnvironment is globally available (see above NodeEnvironmentFailFast.setup)
testEnvironment.registerTestEventHandler(async (event) => {
  if (event.name === "test_fn_failure") {
    await takeScreenshot()
  }
})
```

---

When one `test` fails, other `test` statements in the same `describe` will be skipped. This also works for nested `describe` blocks, but the `describe` blocks **must** have different names.

Executing following test:

```js
describe("TestJest 3 ", () => {
  describe("TestJest 2 ", () => {
    describe("TestJest 1", () => {
      beforeAll(() => expect(1).toBe(2))
      test("1", () => {})
      test("1.1", () => {})
      test("1.2", () => {})
    })

    test("2", () => expect(1).toBe(2))
    test("2.1", () => {})
    test("2.2", () => {})
  })

  test("3", () => {})
  test("3.1", () => expect(1).toBe(2))
  test("3.2", () => {})
})
```

will produce following log:

```sh
 FAIL  suites/test-jest.spec.js
  TestJest 3 
    ✓ 3
    ✕ 3.1 (1 ms)
    ○ skipped 3.2
    TestJest 2 
      ✕ 2
      ○ skipped 2.1
      ○ skipped 2.2
      TestJest 1
        ○ skipped 1
        ○ skipped 1.1
        ○ skipped 1.2

  ● TestJest 3  › TestJest 2  › TestJest 1 › 1

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 1

      2 |   describe("TestJest 2 ", () => {
      3 |     describe("TestJest 1", () => {
    > 4 |       beforeAll(() => expect(1).toBe(2))
        |                                 ^
      5 |       test("1", () => {})
      6 |       test("1.1", () => {})
      7 |       test("1.2", () => {})

      at suites/test-jest.spec.js:4:33

  ● TestJest 3  › TestJest 2  › TestJest 1 › 1.1

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 1

      2 |   describe("TestJest 2 ", () => {
      3 |     describe("TestJest 1", () => {
    > 4 |       beforeAll(() => expect(1).toBe(2))
        |                                 ^
      5 |       test("1", () => {})
      6 |       test("1.1", () => {})
      7 |       test("1.2", () => {})

      at suites/test-jest.spec.js:4:33

  ● TestJest 3  › TestJest 2  › TestJest 1 › 1.2

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 1

      2 |   describe("TestJest 2 ", () => {
      3 |     describe("TestJest 1", () => {
    > 4 |       beforeAll(() => expect(1).toBe(2))
        |                                 ^
      5 |       test("1", () => {})
      6 |       test("1.1", () => {})
      7 |       test("1.2", () => {})

      at suites/test-jest.spec.js:4:33

  ● TestJest 3  › TestJest 2  › 2

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 1

       8 |     })
       9 | 
    > 10 |     test("2", () => expect(1).toBe(2))
         |                               ^
      11 |     test("2.1", () => {})
      12 |     test("2.2", () => {})
      13 |   })

      at Object.<anonymous> (suites/test-jest.spec.js:10:31)

  ● TestJest 3  › 3.1

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 1

      14 | 
      15 |   test("3", () => {})
    > 16 |   test("3.1", () => expect(1).toBe(2))
         |                               ^
      17 |   test("3.2", () => {})
      18 | })
      19 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (suites/test-jest.spec.js:16:31)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       2 failed, 6 skipped, 1 passed, 9 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.638 s, estimated 1 s
```

Comment: should be `const NodeEnvironment = require("jest-environment-node").default`

Answer (score 3):

I've made some kludge but it works for me.

`stopOnFirstFailed.js`:

```
/**
 * This is a realisation of "stop on first failed" with Jest
 * @type {{globalFailure: boolean}}
 */

module.exports = {
    globalFailure: false
};

// Injects to jasmine.Spec for checking "status === failed"
!function (OriginalSpec) {
    function PatchedSpec(attrs) {
        OriginalSpec.apply(this, arguments);

        if (attrs && attrs.id) {
            let status = undefined;
            Object.defineProperty(this.result, 'status', {
                get: function () {
                    return status;
                },
                set: function (newValue) {
                    if (newValue === 'failed') module.exports.globalFailure = true;
                    status = newValue;
                },
            })
        }
    }

    PatchedSpec.prototype = Object.create(OriginalSpec.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: PatchedSpec,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });

    jasmine.Spec = PatchedSpec;
}(jasmine.Spec);

// Injects to "test" function for disabling that tasks
test = ((testOrig) => function () {
    let fn = arguments[1];

    arguments[1] = () => {
        return module.exports.globalFailure ? new Promise((res, rej) => rej('globalFailure is TRUE')) : fn();
    };

    testOrig.apply(this, arguments);
})(test);
```

Imports that file before all tests (before first `test(...)`), for ex my `index.test.js`:

```
require('./core/stopOnFirstFailed'); // before all tests

test(..., ()=>...);
...
```

That code marks all next tests `failed` with label `globalFailure is TRUE` when first error happens.

If you want to exclude `failing`, for ex. some cleanup tests you can do like this:

```
const stopOnFirstFailed = require('../core/stopOnFirstFailed');

describe('some protected group', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        stopOnFirstFailed.globalFailure = false
    });
    test(..., ()=>...);
    ...
```

It excludes whole group from `failing`.

Tested with Node 8.9.1 and Jest 23.6.0

Comment: Doesn't work for `node v10.15.3` and `jest v24.9.0`. I'm getting `TypeError: Class constructor Spec cannot be invoked without 'new'` pointing to line `function PatchedSpec(attrs) {`. Why do your comments mention Jasmine?

Comment: I haven't even tried this because it looks horrible... Is it THAT complicated to basically just process.exit() in Jest from the whole test suite?!

Answer (score 0):

This was my `solution` -- if there are major downsides please let me know, for my purposes it seems to work as intended

*I only have one top-level describe block, for my purposes I want the entire test file to fail when one test fails*

```
export class FailEarly {
  msg: string | undefined;
  failed: boolean = false;
  jestIt: jest.It;

  constructor(jestIt: jest.It) {
    this.jestIt = jestIt;
  }

  test = (name: string, fn: jest.EmptyFunction, timeout?: number) => {
    const failEarlyFn = async () => {
      if (this.failed) {
        throw new Error(`failEarly: ${this.msg}`);
      }

      try {
        await fn();
      } catch (error) {
        this.msg = name;
        this.failed = true;
        throw error;
      }
    };

    this.jestIt(name, failEarlyFn, timeout);
  };
}
```

Gives me a context (class attributes) to store global-esq variables

```
const failEarlyTestRunner = new FailEarly(global.it);

const test = failEarlyTestRunner.test;
const it = failEarlyTestRunner.test;
```

overloads the `test` and `it` functions with my class' method (thus accessing the class attributes)

```
describe('my stuff', () => {
  it('passes', async () => {
    expect(1).toStrictEqual(1);
  })

  test('it fails', async () => {
    expect(1).toStrictEqual(2);
  })

  it('is skipped', async () => {
    expect(1).toStrictEqual(1);
  })
})
```

results in:

```
my stuff
  ✓ can create a sector (2 ms)
  ✕ it fails (2 ms)
  ✕ is skipped (1 ms)


  ● my stuff › it fails

    expect(received).toStrictEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 2
    Received: 1

    > ### |       expect(1).toStrictEqual(2);
          |                 ^
      ### |     });


  ● my stuff › is skipped

    failEarly: it fails

      69 |     const failEarlyFn = async () => {
      70 |       if (this.failed) {
    > 71 |         throw new Error(`failEarly: ${this.msg}`);
         |               ^
      72 |       }
      73 |
      74 |       try {
```

Where each skipped test is failed w/ an error indicating the upstream, failing test

As others have pointed out -- you've got to run jest with the `--runInBand` flag

Hope this helps someone -- if there are meaningful drawbacks or better ways please comment; I'm always happy to learn

Answer (score 0):

I found this Jest Environment for the exact same usage

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-steps

By enabling the steps in a test file

```
/**
 * @jest-environment steps
 */

describe("Tests in this describe runs as steps", () => {
    test("one", () => {});

    describe("inner describe", () => {
       test("inner one", () => {});
       test("inner two", () => {});
    })
    test("two", () => {});
})
```

Failure in `inner one`, skips the execution of `inner two` and `two`

Answer (score -1):

hack the global.jasmine.currentEnv_.fail works for me.

```js
      describe('Name of the group', () => {

        beforeAll(() => {

          global.__CASE_FAILED__= false

          global.jasmine.currentEnv_.fail = new Proxy(global.jasmine.currentEnv_.fail,{
            apply(target, that, args) {
              global.__CASE__FAILED__ = true
              // you also can record the failed info...
              target.apply(that, args)
              }
            }
          )

        })

        afterAll(async () => {
          if(global.__CASE_FAILED__) {
            console.log("there are some case failed");
            // TODO ...
          }
        })

        it("should xxxx", async () => {
          // TODO ...
          expect(false).toBe(true)
        })
      });
```