# Can I make jest run Javascript tests serially?

Tags: jestjs

I have some tests that interact with a database. I have the test code set to clear out the test table before/after each test. This doesn't work with jest though, since it's running multiple tests in parallel, so it starts another test that clears out the test db while the first one's running!

Is it possible to set jest into a serial mode (without writing my own test runner, which seems complicated)?

Comment: with such a set up don't miss [stopping execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250006/jest-stop-test-suite-after-first-fail) after first failure. otherwise results may be unreliable(both successful or failure cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start `Jest` using the [--runInBand](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#runinband) CLI option:

```
jest --runInBand
```

That option causes `Jest` to

> Run all tests serially in the current process