# How to prevent Jest from running tests when an error occurred

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs

I wonder if there is any way to prevent tests from running when we have an error.

For example, in the beforeAll() function. I have tried "return" or "throw" an error but after that, Jest runs all of my tests.
So when my code in the beforeAll() function has an error that can affect other test results, I would like to be able to prevent Jest from running all the tests.

Jest tries to run all the tests even though we already know all the tests would fail.

Comment: There's [no way](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6695) and [Jest's inability to stop testing after a throw or failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250006/jest-stop-test-suite-after-first-fail) has been a problem for 5+ years since I reported it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `bail` in config:

```
 bail: 2      // finish after 2 failed tests
```

or

```
 bail: true  // finish after first
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--bail

To fail your test use:
`fail('something wrong');`

Comment: This seems to describe how to force-fail a specific test. But is there no default way to tell Jest to skip the test if the setup code in beforeAll() (or beforeEach()) fails? I tried calling `fail()` from setup code - in `beforeEach()` in my case - but the test still runs (and fails) as does the teardown code.

Comment: `fail` [should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176642/in-jest-how-can-i-make-a-test-fail#comment126391113_55526098) and [isn't defined](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11698).